# Ha proxy close frontend connection

Tags: audio-streaming, haproxy

So we are dealing with serious amount of connections into our audio relay servers and due to this we need to load balance them with sticky sessions, of course I know that haproxy is the answer for this but we have one big problem

can haproxy send to a backend server and then completely forget the connection...
leaving the connection only reliant on the media server and NOT the proxy?
also this will remove all the bandwidth from the proxy server.

Kind Regards
MooseH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're proxying a connection, you're in the middle of it.  Naturally, there's no way to remove yourself without breaking that connection, as TCP terminates on each side of the proxy.

What you want to do instead is redirect directly to the target servers, with a `302` or `307` and a `Location:` header.  This allows you to balance the load while having clients connect directly to the servers.

Comment: damn i thought so :( that's what we are currently using,

Comment: @Louis What's the issue you're having with redirects?

Comment: Its not really us its our customers, they dont like redirects because they use javascript players, and redirects always start to add problems with "cors"

Comment: If they're using JavaScript players with MSE (the only time their JavaScript would actually have to hit the URL itself in a non-opaque way), then you have CORS problems already.  Fortunately you can easily solve the issue by properly handling OPTIONS requests and applying the correct headers in your response, including for the redirect.  Most of the time though, there's no need for non-opaque access anyway.  The browser can play the audio just fine, and will follow redirects.  Control of the playback is still maintained by JavaScript.